# Vue router doesnt work in the production environment

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I am making a vue-cli application using the webpack template, so far when I run:

```
npm run dev
```

everything renders perfectly and my route works fine. But after running:

```
npm run build
```

I had my dist folder created with the new index.html file and I run my app in production with my server.js file using the following command:

```
node server.js
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

app.use("/", serveStatic( path.join (__dirname, '/dist') ) )


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port)
```

so far when I run the app, evrything renders fine, except when I click on a link to go on another page. It seems to me that vue router is not working on production but works fine on the development environment.

when I click on a link that refers to a /contact route that I have previously defined, I get the following error message:

Cannot GET /contact

this is my src/main.js file

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

this is the src/router/index.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Contact from '../components/Contact.vue'
import Main from '../components/Main.vue'
import CastMembers from '../components/castMembers.vue'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {path:'/', component:Main},
    {path:'/contact', component:Contact},
    {path:'/cast_members', component:CastMembers}],
  mode:'history'
})
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49319175/1640606 it is my answer but I think you have similar issues considering there are somethings missing on your server.js

Comment: hey thanks that really helped! its all working now.

Comment: glad to help ...

Comment: @samayo hi i think you might be able to help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/49615517/7514042