# Having a hard time trying to deploy my vue-cli app to heroku

Tags: javascript, git, heroku, vue.js, vue-cli

I have followed the exact instructions as this tutorial below:

https://codeburst.io/quick-n-clean-way-to-deploy-vue-webpack-apps-on-heroku-b522d3904bc8

except I havent done the Bonus part. When I tried checking my app at:

https://git.heroku.com/proto4bkchat.git

I get the following error message:

```
Method Not Allowed
```

by using this tutorial I was only trying to push the dist folder to heroku.

I have tried many different methods over the past few days, unfortunetly I cant remember everything I tried, I just need help to deploy this app on heroku.

The app works on the dev and production environment but just not on heroku.

the following is a link to my repository:

https://gitlab.com/TitoSalay/BkChatPrototype.git

I have also previously tried deplying the entire root directory using the following server.js file:

```
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback')

const app = express()

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist'))

app.use(staticFileMiddleware)
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}))
app.use(staticFileMiddleware)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'))
})

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log('App now running on port', port)
})
```

when I use :

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following logs:

```
Counting objects: 150, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (142/142), done.
Writing objects: 100% (150/150), 3.65 MiB | 544.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 150 (delta 36), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false

remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  >= 6.0.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   >= 3.0.0
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version >= 6.0.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 9.10.1...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm >= 3.0.0 (replacing 5.6.0)...
remote:        npm 5.8.0 installed
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (not-found)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:
remote:        > chromedriver@2.37.0 install /tmp/build_81bd751efdb3e588f6a9dc1ccc4e3708/node_modules/chromedriver
remote:        > node install.js

remote:        Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip
remote:        Saving to /tmp/chromedriver/chromedriver_linux64.zip
remote:        Received 781K...
remote:        Received 1568K...
remote:        Received 2352K...
remote:        Received 3136K...
remote:        Received 3632K total.
remote:        Extracting zip contents
remote:        Copying to target path /tmp/build_81bd751efdb3e588f6a9dc1ccc4e3708/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chrom
edriver
remote:        Fixing file permissions
remote:        Done. ChromeDriver binary available at /tmp/build_81bd751efdb3e588f6a9dc1ccc4e3708/node_modules/chrome
driver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver
remote:
remote:        > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_81bd751efdb3e588f6a9dc1ccc4e3708/node_modules/w

ebpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
remote:        > node lib/post_install.js
remote:
remote:        added 1249 packages from 969 contributors in 24.841s
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote:
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        removed 1197 packages in 12.146s
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 20.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/proto4bkchat.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

and when I use :

```
git subtree push --prefix dist heroku master
```

I get the following message:

```
No new revisions were found
```

my Procfile:

```
web: node server.js
```

UPDATE:

I now use:

```
heroku open
```

I now get the following error message:

```
Cannot GET /
```

when I run heroku logs --tail I get the following:

```
2018-04-04T14:27:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T14:29:00.808932+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T14:29:00.808932+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 940fed7d by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T14:29:00.827808+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T14:27:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-04T14:29:04.680780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-04-04T14:29:07.017006+00:00 app[web.1]: > bkchat_proto1@1.0.0 start /app
2018-04-04T14:29:07.017009+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-04-04T14:29:07.016979+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-04-04T14:29:07.235631+00:00 app[web.1]: App now running on port 16727
2018-04-04T14:29:07.017011+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-04-04T14:29:08.314843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T14:29:09.911216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_
id=7e0e470c-4edd-45eb-96a1-876e1127b6f1 fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=34ms status=404 bytes=383
 protocol=https

2018-04-04T14:29:09.902613+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
2018-04-04T14:29:10.178203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.c
om request_id=34efa313-9344-4e84-99f2-ce5a185c2308 fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404
 bytes=394 protocol=https
2018-04-04T14:29:10.177004+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET /favicon.ico to /index.html
2018-04-04T14:33:34.284154+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.c
om request_id=0bc35e22-d798-4728-93a6-e3392949925b fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404
 bytes=394 protocol=https
2018-04-04T14:33:34.281911+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET /favicon.ico to /index.html
2018-04-04T14:37:02.733412+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
2018-04-04T14:37:02.734756+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_
id=27e3f301-d6cb-484c-bc3c-108771c16da2 fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=383
protocol=https
2018-04-04T14:38:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T14:39:06.403176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-04-04T14:39:06.403176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-04-04T14:39:06.128567+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9f5cc557 by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T14:39:06.128567+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T14:39:06.960489+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-04-04T14:39:07.062481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-04-04T14:39:09.641745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-04-04T14:39:13.212697+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-04-04T14:39:13.212716+00:00 app[web.1]: > bkchat_proto1@1.0.0 start /app
2018-04-04T14:39:13.212718+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-04-04T14:39:13.212719+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-04-04T14:39:13.816340+00:00 app[web.1]: App now running on port 55452
2018-04-04T14:39:14.207455+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T14:38:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-04T14:39:38.113879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_
id=32acfc35-dd8d-4f15-9246-5c4ddb844f5f fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=96ms status=404 bytes=383
 protocol=https
2018-04-04T14:39:38.099335+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
2018-04-04T14:42:22.977451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2018-04-04T14:42:24.124802+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-04-04T14:42:24.239322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-04-04T14:42:22.807668+00:00 app[api]: Rollback to v1 by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T14:42:22.807668+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk

2018-04-04T20:34:52.103810+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/
" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_id=43e0e34b-c25b-443b-8de2-69de9bada2a6 fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno= connect=
 service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-04-04T20:41:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:42:05.567081+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:42:05.567081+00:00 app[api]: Deploy bc9ece25 by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:42:07.826536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-04-04T20:41:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-04T20:42:05.591139+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:42:09.960096+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-04-04T20:42:09.960114+00:00 app[web.1]: > bkchat_proto1@1.0.0 start /app
2018-04-04T20:42:09.960117+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-04-04T20:42:09.960118+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-04-04T20:42:10.309937+00:00 app[web.1]: App now running on port 46237
2018-04-04T20:42:10.526656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T20:42:13.766514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_
id=cf616fb3-2231-4ba3-b877-7fe6937a1122 fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=63ms status=404 bytes=383
 protocol=https
2018-04-04T20:42:13.759011+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
2018-04-04T20:45:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:46:34.265829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-04-04T20:46:34.268319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-04-04T20:46:33.895581+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:46:33.895581+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a606c93e by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:45:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-04T20:46:34.894801+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-04-04T20:46:34.969267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-04-04T20:46:36.179255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-04-04T20:46:37.895380+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-04-04T20:46:37.895400+00:00 app[web.1]: > bkchat_proto1@1.0.0 start /app
2018-04-04T20:46:37.895402+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-04-04T20:46:37.895401+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-04-04T20:46:38.111326+00:00 app[web.1]: App now running on port 24497
2018-04-04T20:46:38.504681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T20:46:42.928331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_
id=a23b2bfc-9504-412e-8c5f-2b15934a6f6c fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=404 bytes=383
 protocol=https

2018-04-04T20:46:42.921010+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
2018-04-04T20:48:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:49:24.592773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-04-04T20:49:24.596433+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-04-04T20:49:25.543655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-04-04T20:49:25.647753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-04-04T20:49:26.885447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2018-04-04T20:48:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-04T20:49:23.562941+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1d056fa4 by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:49:23.562941+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:49:29.013716+00:00 app[web.1]: App now running on port 48709
2018-04-04T20:49:30.529718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T20:50:06.138034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_
id=605247f4-cc6b-498f-bcd6-20b4c1c1fa6e fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=404 bytes=383
 protocol=https
2018-04-04T20:50:06.127297+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
2018-04-04T20:54:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:55:49.316717+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:55:49.316717+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 346e97a0 by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T20:55:49.557030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-04-04T20:55:49.557620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting

2018-04-04T20:54:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-04T20:55:53.163175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2018-04-04T20:55:56.158535+00:00 app[web.1]: App now running on port 54343
2018-04-04T20:55:57.009235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T20:55:58.573480+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_
id=978a1543-d080-4f10-84ca-6e7f25b3704e fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=106ms status=404 bytes=38
3 protocol=https
2018-04-04T20:55:58.555396+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
2018-04-04T20:56:09.104025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-04-04T20:56:09.168587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

it seems like the app has an issue building the dist folder according to this log:

```
2018-04-04T22:25:30.208992+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:25:30.208992+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:25:30.655267+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:25:30.655267+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:34:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:34:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-04-04T22:35:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:35:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-04-04T22:36:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk

2018-04-04T22:36:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-04-04T22:39:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:39:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-04-04T22:50:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:51:08.581397+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:50:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-04T22:51:08.581397+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2e21be42 by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:51:08.606000+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user salay777@hotmail.co.uk
2018-04-04T22:51:11.160323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2018-04-04T22:51:13.445374+00:00 app[web.1]: App now running on port 56629
2018-04-04T22:51:15.029609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T22:53:04.169972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bkchatproto.herokuapp.com request_i
d=c554f1dc-c588-45e1-aa71-24f11bbab0f6 fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=31ms status=404 bytes=383
protocol=http
2018-04-04T22:53:04.155705+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
2018-04-04T22:53:04.429826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bkchatproto.herokuapp.co
m request_id=23e9f92a-3633-4ba0-b5d6-28d2a0e98ece fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404
bytes=394 protocol=http
2018-04-04T22:53:04.427800+00:00 app[web.1]: Rewriting GET /favicon.ico to /index.html
2018-04-04T22:55:17.562456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com request_
id=7194aade-9ca5-4613-bf28-84f6d239b7d4 fwd="94.193.229.163" dyno=web.1 connect=258ms service=30ms status=404 bytes=3
83 protocol=https
bkchat_proto1/package.json12:33
LFUTF-8JSON0 files1 update
```

so I tried the following in my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bkchat_proto1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bkchat website prototype",
  "author": "Christopher Salay",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run e2e",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "postinstall":"npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

I am trying to install all the dependencies and build the dist folder, but when I push it to heroku, It creates a process that keeps repeating itself and does not stop despite me trying to stop the process via the heroku cli.
The process does not seem to end either so I am usually forced to destroy the app and create it again.

I have also tried the following in my Procfile:

```
web: npm install
web: npm run build
web: node server.js
```

the build also fails on this occasion.

Comment: Heroku has his own Q&A section, where you can access for more helpful information and also you can request for support there.

Comment: Your repository is not public.

Comment: @acdcjunior the repository is now public, I desperately need help on this one.

Comment: Are you using other host than heroku like aws or something?

Comment: I just installed it and local it works just fine. Not sure if I have the time to push it to heroku ... try checking your heroku log when you push it and see what you get first

Comment: @samayo I just added the logs I get when I try pushing to heroku using two different methods.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong to me here, but why are you checking the url: `https://git.heroku.com/proto4bkchat.git` if you check the author's example `https://git.heroku.com/vue-deploy-example.git` you will get the same `Method Not Allowed` message. That url is for heroku to manage your application, not for you to use it

Comment: @samayo so are you saying that the application is wotking? Is so, is the second link you provided the link I should use to see the app?

Comment: Yes lol .. it is working.

Comment: @samayo so how do I check the app then? Because both links are showing the error

Comment: I'm not sure. What is your link again? I can't find it

Comment: I can see ` 503` error response in the log, are you sure your server or the dynos have been started? go to your heroku dashboard and check the dyno status and the console log when you refresh the page

Comment: @samayo I have my own Procfile set up, I will added it on the post above. I get a new error this time saying that it cant find '/'.

Comment: first make sure you are pushing to heroku the built version of your app. Which means, you have to run locally `npm run build` and when it finishes, you push it to heroku, without this it won't work. second, clear your heroku console and try to access your url:  `https://proto4bkchat.herokuapp.com` and let me know what the heroku log shows you

Comment: @samayo, it seems like the build keeps on failing. I am thinking the modules are not installed and the dist folder is proabably not pushed for some reason. Otherwise it would have found the file to render.

Comment: can u add `    "start": "node server.js"` to scripts in package.json? i will try to check tomorrow by pushing to heroku if u want

Answer (score 0):

Its ok, last night I found a solution. I added "heroku-postinstall": "npm install && npm run build" under the scripts section of package.json file to make it work.