# Vue.js Heroku deploy not working

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, vue.js

I'm trying to deploy a Vue.js application I made to Heroku, but I keep getting `Cannot find module '/app/index.js'`.

I feel like I'm just missing something small. Here is the git repo if you are wanting to look through the code. https://github.com/Relofr/calculator

Comment: Check this, I think you are missing some files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317490/error-with-ports-vue-jsnode-js-project-in-heroku/49319175#49319175

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `app.js` (as an example) file in your main directory with basic server configuration. You also have to run `npm run build` before deploying your app.

Follow this tutorial:

https://medium.com/netscape/deploying-a-vue-js-2-x-app-to-heroku-in-5-steps-tutorial-a69845ace489

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have any file with the name `index.js` try to rename `./src/main.js` to `./src/index.js`